# Android how to wait for a thread to finish and notify?

Tags: android, multithreading

The task of the program is to read data from internet and process it.

I am using AsyncTask inside the main class to read data from internet.But AsyncTask will run as separate thread because of that main class finishes before AsyncTask reads the webpage.Now i want the main class to wait for AsyncTask thread to complete(i.e read data from internet) and resume the main class thread.

NOTE :

1. I don't want to do that process in onPostExcecute() method.
2. I don't want to use sleep().

Here is the code

```
    public class MyApp extends Activity {

    String data[] = null;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m1_pm_material_requisitions_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_textview);

    GetData get = new GetData();
    get.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.92.171/erp/index.php"});
    try {
        this.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   //i want the program to wait here till the above task is done and proceed further 

   /* Here the code to process the data in String[] data;....
   ..........
   .......... */      



    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // code to read webpage from internet
    //im using HttpGet to read a webpage

    //now the content of webpage is stored in String[] data

      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), however, you will probably get ANR exception.

Comment: "I don't want to do that process in onPostExcecute() method." - Why? That's exactly what `onPostExecute(...)` is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
this.wait();
```

with

```
get.wait(); // wait until get calls notify()
```

and call

```
this.notify(); // wakeup someone who waiting for me
```

somewhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to process the string in your `AsyncTask` too.  Do as much there as you can.  Only return to the main thread when it's time to update the UI.  And if you really don't want anything in `onPostExecute()`, I suppose you could send your app an `Intent`.